What are the mathematical structures of nominal, ordinal, interval and ratio data?
In Michael Eysenck's fundamentals of psychology, it says

Another factor to consider when deciding which statistical test to use
is the type of data you have obtained. There are four types of data of
increasing levels of precision:.
• Nominal: The data consist of the numbers of participants falling
into various categories (e.g., fat, thin; men, women).
• Ordinal: The data can be ordered from lowest to highest (e.g., the
finishing positions of athletes in a race).
• Interval: The data differ from ordinal data, because the units of
measurement are fixed throughout the range; for example, there is the
same “distance” between a height of 1.82 meters and 1.70 meters as
between a height of 1.70 meters and one of 1.58 meters.


• Ratio: The
data have the same characteristics as interval data, with the
exception that they have a meaningful zero point; for example, time
measurements provide ratio data because the notion of zero time is
meaningful, and 10 seconds is twice as long as 5 seconds. The
similarities between interval and ratio data are so great that they
are sometimes combined and referred to as interval/ratio data.

Is nominal data the same as categorical data?
Is ordinal data the same as data from an ordered set, mathematically speaking?
What are interval data and ratio data mathematically? Are interval data exactly data from a semigroup (similar to a group without necessarily an identity element)? Are ratio data exactly data from a group?

"Is nominal data the same as categorical data?". It's always been my understanding that "categorical data" include nominal and ordinal data. So "nominal data" is a type of categorical data, not a synonym of categorical data. From wikipedia: "Ordinal data is a categorical, statistical data type [...]".

On the other hand, the tag [tag:categorical-data] seems to completely contradict that: "Categorical (also called nominal) data can take on a limited number of possible values called categories.". I'll ask a specific question about that asking for references, because now I'm unsure about it.

Here it is: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/656778/164936

Please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23200 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17029 for elaboration.

@whuber  normial is only 1/4 of my post

And...? The duplicate addresses all of Stevens' types and answers all of your questions.
